# Is it possible to get the element that you originally assigned the listener to instead of the current "target" upon the even firing?

Tags: javascript

So a simple example:

```js
var outer_div = document.querySelector("#div1");
outer_div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
div {
 position:fixed;
 left:0;top:0;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"><div id="div2"></div></div>
```

Whenever I slide over the 2 nested divs, the target is always the inner div. Is there a way to get the element that the event listener was originally attached to no matter what child gets in the way?

Comment: Yes, use `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely! Simply use '**[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)**' instead of `e.target`:

```js
var outer_div = document.querySelector("#div1");
outer_div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```css
div {
 position:fixed;
 left:0;top:0;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"><div id="div2"></div></div>
```

As a DOM event handler, `this` provides the context of the element **firing** the event:

> When a function is used as an event handler, its this is set to the element the event fired from (some browsers do not follow this convention for listeners added dynamically with methods other than addEventListener).

Hope this helps! :)